# How can I select only the rows with `{ ... "type": "Longitude" ... }` in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm using `@vercel/postgres` in a Next.js project.

I can successfully select rows from a PostgreSQL database, but want to only select those rows whose JSONB column contain a value (not key) of `Longitude`.

The table is simple:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      json JSONB,
      "at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
      "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

My query is:

```sql
SELECT
     id,
     at,
     json -> 'uplink_message' -> 'decoded_payload' -> 'messages' -> 0 AS message
    FROM events 
    -- WHERE ("json" -> 'uplink_message' -> 'decoded_payload' -> 'messages' -> 0)::jsonb ? 'Longitude' 
    ORDER BY at 
    DESC LIMIT ${limit}
```

but the (commented out) `WHERE` clause results in no rows being selected.

I'm new to PostgreSQL, so please forgive (but also mention) any mistakes.

An example of a row I'd like to select is:

```json
{
  "id": 2052,
  "at": "2024-02-14T15:03:15.000Z",
  "json": {
    "received_at": "2024-02-14T15:03:17.926885957Z",
    "uplink_message": {
      "decoded_payload": {
        "messages": [
          [
            {
              "type": "Longitude",
              "measurementId": "4197",
              "measurementValue": "-1.40000"
            },
            {
              "type": "Latitude",
              "measurementId": "4198",
              "measurementValue": 50.9000
            },
            {
              "type": "Battery",
              "measurementId": "3000",
              "measurementValue": 94
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(others don't have the lat/long messages)

Comment: Apparently `json -> 'uplink_message' -> 'decoded_payload' -> 'messages' -> 0` returns an array. Did you mean `json -> 'uplink_message' -> 'decoded_payload' -> 'messages' -> 0 -> 0 ->> 'type' = 'Longitude'`?

Comment: Apologies, my example row didn't actually match what's in the DB, it was based on the results I was getting. I've updated it now, so you can see that (for some reason) the `messages` property is an array of an array of objects.

Comment: Yes, and exactly that is why your condition was not matching any rows. Does handling this solve your problem or do you need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this where the query transforms the messages array into a set of rows using `jsonb_array_elements`, then filters those rows based on the value of the '`type`' key.

```
SELECT
  id,
  "at",
  json -> 'uplink_message' -> 'decoded_payload' -> 'messages' -> 0 AS message
FROM
  events,
  jsonb_array_elements(json->'uplink_message'->'decoded_payload'->'messages') AS msg
WHERE
  msg ->> 'type' = 'Longitude'
ORDER BY
  "at" DESC
LIMIT ${limit}
```